# I can't connect to my node express server on any other device on my network

Tags: node.js, express, networking

Here is my server.js code:

```
var express        =         require("express");
var app            =         express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function () 
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Really simple, I just want to see it working on my other devices before I continue.

It works fine obviously on my laptop I'm running it off, but nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing `'0.0.0.0'` from your `app.listen` call?

Comment: Yes I've tried removing '0.0.0.0'. And what's wrong with listening?

Comment: Did you check the firewall on the machine where the script is running?

Comment: What should I be checking for with the firewall?

Comment: Well how about you let us know what feedback do you get ? Try console logging something? Have you checked if port 3000 is actually available ?

Comment: Turned off firewall and it worked. How can I allow firewall to remain on without it affecting this server?

Comment: @numberjak add the running application as an exception. This on the other hand is a totally different question.

Answer (score 1):

- Try removing the '0.0.0.0'
- You also have a missing bracket.

Try This:

```
    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
    });
```

Read more:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback

Comment: Tried both and neither changed anything

Answer (score 1):

Try this maybe:

```
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var service = express();

service.use(service.router);

service.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
});

var server = http.createServer(service);

app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```